# Changing the color of single ticks not working anymore

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, xticks, yticks

I upgraded to matplotlib 3.3.3 and I can no longer change the color of a single tick when plotting.

Using matplotlib 3.2.1 the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.ylim(0,3)

ax = plt.gca() 

y_label_positions = [0,1,2,3]
y_label_strings = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]

ax.set_yticks(y_label_positions)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_label_strings)

ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()[2].set_markeredgewidth(5)
ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()[2].set_color("red")

plt.savefig("foo.pdf")
```

works fine and changes the tick's size and color,

but the same code with Matplotlib 3.3.3 only changes the size of the tick, not its color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_markeredgecolor`:

```
ax.yaxis.get_ticklines()[2].set_markeredgecolor("red")
```

Output:

[image]